# What is the exact way to embed jQuery and Bootstrap in .php file?

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

What is the accurate and correct way to include Bootstrap and jQuery code in a .php file that makes everything works well. Give me a starter template if you could.I tried Bootstrap's template and wrote some jQuery but that doesn't work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<!-- Required meta tags -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- jQuery first, then Tether, then Bootstrap JS. -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <h1>Get in touch!</h1>

    <form>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Please, enter your email adress">
            <small class="text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="subject">Subject</label>
            <input type="text" id="subject" class="form-control">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">

            <label for="content">What would you like to ask us?</label>
            <textarea rows="3" class="form-control" id="content"></textarea>

        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

    </form>

</div>


<script type="text/javascript">

    $("form").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var error = "<p><strong>There were error(s) in your form:</strong></p>";

        if($("#email").val() == "") {

            error += "<p>The email field is required.</p>";

        } else if($("#subject").val() == "") {

            error += "<p>The subject field is required.</p>";

        } else if($("#content").val() == "") {

            error += "<p>The content field is required.</p>"

        }

    });

</script>  




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please post the code that you have tried. With your current question it seems like you have done no research and are just asking for us to do the work for you.

Comment: @Matthew Sorry Matthew, I will edit my question although I wanted just few tips but I will share my code.

Comment: No worries, that is just a rule of thumb here. Always make sure to show your work. What is the error you get in the console from the jQuery you have written? Is there a reason you are using jQuery.slim instead of the full jQuery package?

Comment: *"that doesn't work"* is not a proper problem statement. Are errors thrown? What does happen?

Comment: @chalietfl I mean jQuery Specifically.

Comment: Try to switch out your jQuery tag with this one: `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`. Right now you are including jQuery slim which has some jquery function removed from it. Not sure if this is the issue but it is worth a try.

Comment: Sorry for all, I just worried when my code editor didn't auto-complete the jQuery functions so I thought it wasn't working but it seems to be working. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Matthew Thank you, that is much better!!

Comment: I have added my comment as an answer so it can be accepted and this thread complete. Glad it worked for you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to switch your current jQuery.slim include to the full jQuery.

switch

`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

With

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jqu‌​ery.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b‌​8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`